# How to add two items at the same index in an entity in CoreData iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an entity called `Items` with two attributes `itemName` and `itemPrice`.

I have created a `NSManagedObject` and the data is being inserted, however I want to insert `itemName` and `itemPrice` at the same index.

```
func addItem(name: String, price: Double){
    var items = [NSManagedObject]();

    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!


    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Items",
        inManagedObjectContext:
        managedContext);

    let itemName = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
        insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext);

    let itemPrice = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext);


    itemName.setValue(name, forKey: "itemName");
    itemPrice.setValue(price, forKey: "itemPrice");


    var error: NSError?
    if !managedContext.save(&error) {
        println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }

    items.append(itemName)
    items.append(itemPrice);
}
```

When I execute this code it seems to enter the data as two different writes (Which I know it is) but I don't know how to add them together as one. For example when run

```
items.append(itemName)
```

Outputs:

```
itemName = Car;
itemPrice = nil;
```

And

```
items.append(itemPrice)
```

Outputs:

```
 itemName = nil ;
 itemPrice = 10000;
```

How do I add the two attributes together?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `items.append(itemName)` and `items.append(itemPrice)` you should create a new NSManagedObject of type Items and set it's attributes as that's what itemName and itemPrice are

Comment: I'm trying to store the two values given for `itemName` and `itemPrice` in `Items` entity

Comment: and you store them by creating a new NSManagedObject in the Items entity

Comment: Is that not what `var items = [NSManagedObject]()` is suppose to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of an NSManagedObject as a row in a database table. The Entity name is like the table name and the attributes of the entity are like the columns.

You only need to create one new managed object (row) for the 'Items' entity (table) and then set the attributes (columns) on that entity -

```
func addItem(name: String, price: Double){

    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!


    let newItem =  NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Items",
        inManagedObjectContext:
        managedContext);


    newItem.setValue(name, forKey: "itemName");
    newItem.setValue(price, forKey: "itemPrice");


    var error: NSError?
    if !managedContext.save(&error) {
        println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create an NSManagedObject Subclass:
1. Go to your data model
2. Select the entity
3. Go to the Editor tab in the navigation bar of your mac
4. Select Create NSManagedObject Subclass

Once you've done that implement this function:

```
func createItem(name: String, price: Int) {

    let newEvent = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Items", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as NSManagedObject
    newItem.itemName = name
    newItem.itemPrice = price
}
```